# Script to check if Ports are running

Tags: perl, aix

I need help in order to check if two local ports are running in my box and if that is the case open a port.

For Example:

DB2 Port : 50001
MQ Port: 1414

If both are open, Open Port 45 for listening if either of those is not, Close the script port.

Im running AIX 7.1

Comment: Theres a module for that  http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/IO-Socket-PortState-0.03/

Answer (score 0):

```
use Socket;

socket(HSOCK, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('TCP'));
$address = sockaddr_in(50001, inet_aton('0.0.0.0'));
if (! bind(HSOCK, $address)) {
  $address = sockaddr_in(1414, inet_aton('0.0.0.0'));
  if (! bind(HSOCK, $address)) {
    $address = sockaddr_in(45, inet_aton('0.0.0.0'));
    bind(HSOCK, $address) or die "bind 45 failed";
    listen(HSOCK, 5) or die "listen 45 failed";
     . . . # accept / loop
  }
}
```

Comment: i always get bind 45 failed at line 11.

Comment: thanks rook, i have to run the command with sudo, however, nothing happens :/

Comment: @user1961382 this piece of code in perl, starts listen on 45 TCP (local) port if 50001 and 1414 ports are active on localhost, is that what you'd like? :)